# Reverting of CentOS file to previous state after power outage

Tags: centos, filesystems, fsck

There was some issues with the power supply for a CentOS 7 server which caused it to shutdown. After sorting the supply issue and turning on the server it was found that the `/etc/hosts` file which contained the static IP had returned to the IP address that had been changed approximately a week ago. Is it possible that the issue with the power supply caused this change? If so why did this occur and how do I find more information on this (such as what other changes were made)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that the issue of the power supply caused this change?

Considering the age not very likely but possible. I'd personally be looking elsewhere.

> If so why did this occur and how do I find more information on this (such as what other changes were made)?

An unexpected system restart/shutdown often leads to a fsck utility pass, however nothing is logged in the process, so it's impossible to know what really happened.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that a faulty power supply reverts the contents of a file to a previous state.

What likely happened: the entry in the `/etc/hosts` file was changed manually to IP #2, the machine was not rebooted afterwards, and the machine has a configuration that sets that entry in `/etc/hosts` to IP #1.

If you had rebooted the machine manually, it would have happened the same.

Comment: I have changed the entry to IP #2 and manually rebooted the machine. The file is still currently IP#2 which I believe indicates that the machine is not configured to IP#1.